# Spring Data Rest: ResourceProcessor configuration is not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a strange behaviour with a Spring Data Rest implementation (version 2.5.2.RELEASE).

I'm trying to register a `@Bean` of `ResourceProcessor<Resource<Entity>>`, but there is something strange.

I'm trying with two kinds of solutions:

**1)** Declaring the `@Bean` in a class:

```
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<Author>> authorProcessor() {

    return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<Author>>() {

        @Override
        public Resource<Author> process(Resource<Author> resource) {

            System.out.println("method process of bean ResourceProcessor of class RepositoryBaseConfiguration");
            return resource;
        }
    };
}
```

**2)** Implementing the interface `ResourceProcessor`:

```
@Component
public class AuthorResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Author>> {

    @Override
    public Resource<Author> process(Resource<Author> resource) {
        System.out.println("method process of class AuthorResourceProcessor");
        return resource;
    }

}
```

**The processors are completely ignored: the message is never printed.**

I noticed that the class `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorInvoker` has a constructor:

```
public ResourceProcessorInvoker(Collection<ResourceProcessor<?>> processors) {

    //...
}
```

**This constructor is invoked 2 times** at the start of the application instead of only one time (as I will expect), and I don't understand why.

The first time, the "processors" variable is solved with the two beans (as expected) and with the bean `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileResourceProcessor`.

But the second time, the "processors" variable is solved with only the bean `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileResourceProcessor`.

The second configuration @Override the first one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem depends on the configurations loaded at the startup of the application.

I had this configuration on the `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-web-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

So, the `ContextLoaderListener` loaded the correct configuration in the first time; the "`load-on-startup`" property of the servlet "`RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet`" launch a second context configuration load.

I also had a custom class that extended `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`, but this custom class was ignored by the moment that the constructor of `RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet` **load the default** `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`, **causing the lost of the configurations**.

To solve that issue I have created a **custom** `RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet` in this way:

```
public class AppRepositoryRestDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AppRepositoryRestDispatcherServlet() {
        configure();
    }

    public AppRepositoryRestDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext) {
        super(webApplicationContext);
        configure();
    }

    private void configure() {
        setContextClass(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class);
        setContextConfigLocation(RepositoryBaseConfiguration.class.getName());
    }

}
```

The class is the same as `RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet`, with the only difference that in the setContextConfigLocation is passed the custom class that extends `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` (`RepositoryBaseConfiguration` in this example).

Obviously I had to update the `web.xml` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.AppRepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In this way, the configuration is correctly loaded and mantained.